# Numpy correlate x-axis is shifted

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, correlation, cross-correlation

I have two signals that I'm trying to see their correlation lag:

[image]

It looks like they are synced, so I expect the `correlate` function to give minimum at zero (because they have anti-correlation every ~100 timesteps).

However, using this code:

```
yhat1 = np.load('cor1.npy')
yhat2 = np.load('cor2.npy')

corr = np.correlate(yhat1 - np.mean(yhat1), 
                    yhat2 - np.mean(yhat2),
                    mode='same')
plt.plot(corr)
plt.show()
```

I'm getting the following (I tried to use `'full '` and `'same'` in the mode and got the same result):

[image]

Why the minimum is not at 0 as expected but at 250?
Why it seems like there are other significant peaks on both sides of the minimum?

data is [here](https://easyupload.io/7882ya)

Comment: looks like it is not using `mode='same'`. The last plot is from 0 to 1000?

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's correlation function returns you the auto/cross correlation function depending on the inputs you give. Correlation is same as convolution except you dont apply time reversal to one of the signals. In other words, apply a sliding dot-product between signals.

At t=0, it's normal to get zero correlation as one signal has zero at t=0. However,as you perform this further, signals are fluctuating both in magnitude and sign. Due to (relatively) extreme peaks of signals to each other at different times, correlatino is fluctuiating. THe huge peak is at t=500 because at theat time full overlap occurs between two signals. This happens as your signals extreme peaks are aligned at that moment. After t=500, your overlapped regions decrease and obsreve that the behavior is similar to the case before we've reached to t<500.